# KnownType exception in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

The scenario:

I need to pass a `ControllerContext` object from my `ASP.NET MVC Controllers` as parameter to a WCF method.

My parameter class:

```
[MessageContract]
public class FileParameter
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public ControllerContext Context { get; set; }

   [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

Calling the method in the controller:

```
 public class ReportController : Controller
{
public ActionResult GeneratePdf()
    {
        var file = new FileParameter();
        {
           Context = this.ControllerContext;
           FileName = "test"
        };

       TestProxy.GetInstance().GetPdfByte(file);
    }
  }
```

i get the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type
'App.Web.Controllers.ReportController' with data contract name 
'Dog:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Serialization' is not expected. 
Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to 
the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute 
or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
```

Whats the problem here? It understand that the ControllerContext must be generic the WCF would accept the `ReportController` context as a `ControllerContext`.

Edit
Wcf Method:

```
   public byte[] GetBytes(FileParameterfile file)
   {
      var rotativa = new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("Index");

     return rotativa.BuildPdf(file.Context);
   }
```

Comment: that is a bad idea - there are some unserializable things in there.

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, but, whats the alternative? i need to pass the context to the method.

Comment: just create your own object.

Comment: representing the context you mean?

Comment: yes with exactly what you need.

Comment: The problem is that im using a 3d party dll in the WCF method, and this dll needs a ControllerContext as parameter.

Comment: That seems wrong - perhaps you can share that.

Comment: This is brainless. Passing a .NET, platform-specific type over WCF makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

From the error it looks like you are trying to pass a ReportController over wcf by assigning it to a DataMember of Type Controller. In order to do that you need to added the following to where the Controller class is define like this:

```
[KnownType(ReportController)]
class Controller...
```

If Controller is a built in .Net type this will not work...